# Работа с нестандартными символами букв в re

Tags: python, linux, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно работать с разными языками при парсинге строк регекспами. Я использую в регекспах "\w", но в итоге под этот регексп подходят только латинские символы как буквы. Всякие символы из других языков почему-то не проходят. Я имею ввиду символы из языков типа испанского и португальского, типа: u"ñ" и u"Ç". Я уже пробовал выставлять re.U флаг, но видимо что бы они проходили как \w у меня должна стоять локаль языка с такими буквами.

Пока спасаюсь костылем, ввожу после \w все остальные подобные символы, но поскольку в проекте используется все больше языков символов становиться все больше, я наверное сломаю пальцы когда буду вбивать китайский. =)

Что можно сделать что бы re начала воспринимать все эти символы из других языков под \w?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.U` должна была сработать. В какой кодировке у вас строки?

> но видимо что бы они проходили как w у меня должна стоять локаль

Ну, попробовать `re.L` можно, но во-первых, у вас действительно должны быть скомпилированы все необходимые локали, а во-вторых, питон в локалях с кодировкой UTF-8 иногда сходит с ума.

Comment: вы правы, я просто не знал что в re.sub нельзя выставлять флаги, пришлось сначала сделать re.compile() с флагом... Спасибо.

Comment: @rnd_d: можно в `re.sub()` использовать флаги: `re.sub("a", "b", "A", flags=re.I)` -- интерфейс неудачный там 4ый порядковый параметр `count` (сколько замен делать), а не `flags`.